# Two dimensional array to calculate amount in a form,javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a order form where user selects the quality of image(from dropdownlist),type of item(from radio button),glossy finish(checkbox checked then $1) and quantity(textbox),based on the selection of user when clicks on calculate button the cost of selected items textbox should populate with total amount.

(qualityofimage) 
                hard-copy  poster coffee mug T-shirt  (type of item)

Good            8.99      9.99   10.99       11.99
Very good       9.99      10.99  11.99       12.99
Excellent       10.99     11.99   12.99      13.99

for example:
if quality of image is Good,type of item is hard-copy,glossy finish is checked and quantity as 1:
total amount=(8.99+1)*1.

I am new to javascript and tried using two dimensional array to calculate the amount but not getting the correct result.Any help is appreciated.

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="orderform" name="orderform">
            <!--Order form-->
        <div id="items">
            Types of items
            <input type="radio" id="items" name="items" value="1" >Hard-copy Prints
            <input type="radio" id="items" name="items" value="2" >Posters
            <input type="radio" id="items" name="items" value="3" >Coffee Mugs
            <input type="radio" id="items" name="items" value="4" >T-shirts
        </div>
<div id="qualityofimage">    
        Quality of Images
            <select name="quality" id="quality">
                <option value="1" selected>Good</option>
                <option value="2">Very Good</option>
                <option value="3">Excellent</option>
            </select>
            </div>
<div>
        Glossy finish
            <input type="checkbox" name="gf" id="gf">
            </div>
        <div>Quantity
            <input type="text" id ="qty" name="qty" size="5">
            </div>
            <div><input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="display()"></div>
<div>Total
          <input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" readonly="readonly">
          </div>
                </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var array=[[8.99,9.99,10.99],[9.99,10.99,11.99],[10.99,11.99,12.99],[11.99,12.99,13.99]];
function display()
{
    var row = document.querySelector('input[name="quality"]:selected').value;
   var column = document.querySelector('input[name="items"]:checked').value;
    var gf=document.getElementById("gf");
    var qty=document.getElementById("qty").value;
    var total=0;
    if(gf.checked)
    {
        total= (array[row][column]+1)*qty;
    }
    else
    {
        total= (array[row][column])*qty;
    }
   document.getElementById("cost").value = total;
}
```

Comment: Have you done a console.log( "Row: " + row + " | Column: " + column ); to see if those are getting the right values?

Answer (score 0):

There's only one issue: `:selected` is a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/), so it won't work with `document.querySelector`.

You're probably looking for `$("select option:selected")`.

So, it'd be:

```
var row = $('select option:selected').val();
```

Once I changed that, it worked fine.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/6ZPhz/)